# Sudo user running app: can it be elevated to be root by app?

Tags: ubuntu, security, sudo

Sudo user running app: can it be elevated to be root by app?

e.g.,

user "user_xyz" is a regular user in sudo group.

```
 sudo command
```

Does not require password.

If the user run an app, can the app elevate the user to be a root user causing security issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> user "user_xyz" is a regular user in sudo group.

## Do not add untrusted users to the sudo group

The **sudo** group in Ubuntu is a special purpose group, making a regular user a member there grants them full administrator rights; and they are no longer a "regular" user. By design and by default that group membership grants the user unrestricted `sudo` privileges. Administrators in the sudo group can use the `sudo` command to run any command or tool with full privileges and access all data and settings of all other users, services and components on that system.

```
# Uuntu defaults in /etc/sudoers
...
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Group membership in ***the sudo group also grants administrator privileges elsewhere*** in addition to sudo, for example in PolicyKit / [polkit](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man8/polkit.8.html) enforced policies for (GUI) applications.

```
# Ubuntu defaults in /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

---

> If the user run an app, can the app elevate the user to be a root user causing security issue?

Even when you don't add the user to the sudo group and instead create a [`sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/)  policy that will only allow your user to run a single command/application with sudo and at elevated `root` privileges, be aware that often there unexpected ways in which the user might be able to use that limited access to gain more privileges  than you intended.

See for example the Q&A here about using sudo rights to a text editor to gain more privileges : [Why is it risky to give sudo vim access to ordinary users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181492/why-is-it-risky-to-give-sudo-vim-access-to-ordinary-users)

Even limited [`sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/sudoers.man/)  policies should only be granted to users that are to be trusted.